# Can aircraft depart/arrive after another aircraft has sprayed snow on the runway?

Tags: safety, aircraft-performance, weather, runways

Does snow spray affect runway surface friction? The weather was bitterly cold on March 18th, 2018 and Birmingham airport was covered with snow. As you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/NHw1QDn5mxM), an A380 sprays snow on the runway when arriving and departing.

[image]
(Frame from video)

Answer (score 4):

Aircraft can land in snowy weather without a problem, the fact that there is a little bit of snow on the runway does not change that. The amount of snow can cause problems if it too deep and will interfere with the engines/landing gear struts etc.

The snow sprayed on the runway by the A380 is just a small film and no problem for aircraft to take-off and land on. The runway can become a bit more slippery decreasing the braking performance of the aircraft.